# Picture box drawing image

Tags: .net, vb.net, picturebox

I have a question. Is it Possible to save the drawing image of Picture box?

Because I have a system that user will sign in picture box using pentablet or let say mouse. Then the user can save this image as its signature.

This is my output. Just a paint inside a picture box:
[image]

Is it possible to save this drawing image as jpeg? if it is then how?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Whatever you have drawn on the `PictureBox`, you also draw on the `Image` in the `PictureBox` when you're ready to save.  Here's a demo that includes that functionality: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426684-Very-Simple-Drawing-Program&highlight=

Comment: Note that, once you've drawn on the `Image`, you can call `Image.Save` to save that to a file.

Comment: @jmcilhinney is there a posible code like when clicking save button will do the save task. It because that is the only code missing in my sysmtem

Comment: Yes, and I have provided you with an example of the code you need to use.  If it's too much trouble for you to look at that demonstration and then write the code you need then that's your prerogative.

Comment: Yah i also got it. mix my code and that. Thank so much.

Comment: Excellent.  If you have a solution then you should post it as an answer and accept it. I didn't provide an answer because I didn't want to write enough code for a full solution but, if you solve your own issue, you should always provide your own answer.  It means that others won't waste time coming to provide an answer that you no longer need.

Comment: @jmcilhinney done posting it. late post because my time yesterday is so busy. But thanks anyway. Godbless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i save the paint in my picture box as imgae, But in .png file ext.

```
Private Sub ts_btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ts_btnSave.Click
    If Detector = 0 Then 'Detectore here is a variable where an identifier to inform me if the user paint something in picturebox or not.
        MessageBox.Show("No Signature Found", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) = vbYes Then
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
            PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height))
            bmp.Save("D:Images\Filename.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png) 'File name must be flexible so that it will not replace the old image.
            bmp.Dispose()
            Me.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Best regards to `@jmcilhinney` for the effort